# Why do I have to disconnect and connect for internet all the time?

Tags: internet

Currently, I have to disconnect and connect again to use the internet for my Linux computer. It works fine for my tablet.

Do you know what could be the reason for that?

When I use the internet for more than a minute or so it simply doesn't work any more.

I am connected without a wire.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 16 Petra \n \l
$ uname -a
Linux pc08 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:40:f2:93:ff:ab  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:534518 (534.5 KB)  TX bytes:534518 (534.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b7:0d:f1:35:65  
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9eb7:dff:fef1:3565/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:58102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:63722853 (63.7 MB)  TX bytes:6852895 (6.8 MB)
$ traceroute 4.2.2.2
traceroute to 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  13.115 ms  13.090 ms  13.069 ms
 2  * * *
 3  te-0-1-0-5-sur01.pittsburgh.pa.pitt.comcast.net (68.85.234.9)  180.382 ms  180.372 ms  180.356 ms
 4  162-151-21-129-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net (162.151.21.129)  179.660 ms te-0-10-0-13-ar03.pittsburgh.pa.pitt.comcast.net (69.139.168.57)  174.513 ms te-0-8-0-12-ar03.pittsburgh.pa.pitt.comcast.net (68.85.75.189)  179.609 ms
 5  he-4-14-0-0-cr01.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.94.185)  186.009 ms  186.002 ms  185.987 ms
 6  ae12.edge1.NewYork2.level3.net (4.68.127.1)  185.288 ms  54.871 ms  81.634 ms
 7  vlan51.ebr1.NewYork2.Level3.net (4.69.138.222)  103.096 ms  173.070 ms vlan52.ebr2.NewYork2.Level3.net (4.69.138.254)  173.044 ms
 8  ae-48-48.ebr2.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.201.37)  173.010 ms ae-47-47.ebr1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.201.45)  172.915 ms  172.908 ms
 9  ae-62-62.csw1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.148.34)  172.821 ms ae-92-92.csw4.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.148.46)  172.947 ms ae-91-91.csw4.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.134.78)  171.584 ms
10  ae-2-70.edge2.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.155.80)  172.802 ms  172.808 ms ae-1-60.edge2.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.155.16)  172.732 ms
11  b.resolvers.Level3.net (4.2.2.2)  172.808 ms  172.760 ms  47.988 ms
$ lspci | grep -i ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been hit by this before. It seems that some wireless cards don't play well with 802.11n on *nix. The answer (if this is indeed your problem), as explained [here](http://technosopher.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/wireless-slow-flaky-crashing-router-intel-6300-6205-5100-6300-chipse/) for example, is to disable 802.11n altogether:

```
echo "options iwlagn 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf
sudo modprobe -rf iwlagn
sudo modprobe -v iwlagn
```

To find out what type of wireless card you have:

```
lspci | grep -i ethernet
```

Comment: When I execute the first command I get `bash: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf: Permission denied`

Comment: @moose Please see the updates after Stephane's edit. I carelessly copied the command from the referenced link without checking it for correctness. Also, are you sure you have `sudo` configured properly?

Comment: The file `iwlagn.conf` didn't exist. So I've created it and I've executed `sudo modprobe -rf iwlagn` after that. I got `FATAL: Module iwlagn not found.`

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/285567/10425

Comment: I show this same thing in these A's as well: [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116151/wi-fi-working-on-and-off-mostly-off-on-a-hp-laptop-take-two/116156#116156), [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/recurrent-loss-of-wireless-connectivity/90689#90689), and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/system-went-unresponsive-and-had-to-hard-reboot/101583#101583)

Comment: Thanks. +1. My wireless module is not `iwlagn` but `iwlwifi`. There is no such file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` either. Shall I run `echo "options iwlagn 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`? My question is here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163028/why-does-my-wlan0-stop-working